# I want to sort data of a csv file (A to Z ) .But Its showing Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is

```
import sys
import csv
import operator
data = csv.reader(open("clean.csv","r"))
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
with open("Final42.csv", "w") as sorter:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(sorter)
    for row in sortedlist:
        fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

I am getting Error **IndexError: list index out of range**

Sample Data

- 2 /,140,0.566,455,1069,1.097,1584,0.38,1.989,85.71%,0.1,79.4
- 01_Launch,140,0.566,455,1069,1.097,1584,0.38,1.989,85.71%,0.1,79.4
- 109 /api/Login,140,0.03,30,34,0.035,43,0.026,0.048,0.00%,0.1,0.1
- 110 /api/ProspectDashBoard,140,0.008,7,8,0.009,22,0.005,0.22,0.00%,0.1,0.7

My csv file contain 2000 lines and 12 columns

Comment: Your example code runs fine

Comment: Yes but its not working when the row count is 400 and column count is 12

Comment: You have 12 columns in your example and 4 rows. I took the liberty of copying the 4 lines 100 times and have this sorted. As expected it works. I suggest you have a look at the line where it breaks down.

Comment: I have written there are 2000 lines and 12 columns .So it is showing error..

Comment: I repeated with 2000 lines and 12 columns and it works. One line in your csv file does not match the general pattern. I suggest you look through it. Using the print statement to see where something goes wrong is fairly common in debugging.